# In bash, how do I create an array of committed files that still exist on my file system?

Tags: bash, shell-script, filesystems, git

I'm using a bash script to create a Git hook.  I want to run a process (linting) against files I'm committing.  I only want to run the process if the files actually exist (in other words, not consider files taht were deleted from in my commit).  I tried this

```
    CHANGED_FILES=$(git diff --cached --name-only | grep ".js$")
    echo "$CHANGED_FILES"
    
    if [ -n "$CHANGED_FILES" ]; then
      REAL_FILES=()
      for pathname in "${CHANGED_FILES[@]}"; do
        if [ -e "$pathname" ]; then
            REAL_FILES+=( "$pathname" )
        fi
      done

  echo "real files are ..."
  echo "$REAL_FILES"
```

but the above only works if there is a single file changed.  If there are two or more files changed, nothing happens and my output just looks like

```
    src/app/test1.js
    src/app/test2.js
    real files are ...
```

So nothign is getting saved for "REAL_FILES" when the CHANGED_FILES array contains 2 or more files that actually exist.

How can I fix the above?

Comment: This is an array assignment: `REAL_FILES=(...)`. This isn't: `CHANGED_FILES=$(...)`. This expands a single scalar value: `"$REAL_FILES"`. This expands all values of an array: `"${CHANGED_FILES[@]}"`. You should see some conflicts here.

Comment: You aren't populating an array CHANGED_FILES, you're populating a string variable.

Comment: What would that look like in code?

Comment: You really don't want to use CAPS for shell variable names. Since, [by convention](https://stackoverflow.com/q/673055/1081936), global environment variables are capitalized, it is bad practice to also use caps for your own, local variables because this can lead to naming collisions and hard to find bugs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your script is that CHANGED_FILES is a scalar variable, not an array.

Try:

```
CHANGED_FILES=( $(git diff --cached --name-only | grep ".js$") )
```

i.e. add parentheses around the `$(git...)` command substitution.

Note that this is subject to the usual shell word splitting, so if there is any chance(*) that there might be spaces/newlines/shell metacharacters in any of the pathnames, you should use `mapfile` and [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution) instead of [command substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution), with the `-z` option for NUL separators with both `git diff` and `grep`.  For example:

```
mapfile -d '' -t CHANGED_FILES < \
  <(git diff -z --cached --name-only | grep -z '\.js$')
```

BTW, `mapfile` and `readarray` are synonyms in bash.  See `help mapfile` for details.  In `ksh`, it's `readarray` only and `mapfile` doesn't exist.

(*) there is **always** a chance for this because those characters are valid filename characters on unix filesystems.  The only character which isn't valid in a pathname is NUL (and the only characters not valid in the filename portion of a pathname are `/` and NUL).  So, you should always write your scripts defensively and assume that there will always be at least one such annoying filename somewhere.  i.e. always use the `mapfile` version.

---

BTW, if you want to print ALL elements of the $REAL_FILES array (instead of just the first element), then use the `[@]` subscript OR use `declare -p` / `typeset -p` (which is better for debugging. and for generating output which can be executed in bash without quoting/whitespace problems).

e.g. instead of this:

```
echo "$REAL_FILES"
```

do this:

```
echo "${REAL_FILES[@]}"
```

or this:

```
typeset -p REAL_FILES
```

(`declare` vs `typeset` is another `bash` vs `ksh` discrepancy.  ksh had `readarray` and `typeset`, then bash copied them from ksh and renamed them to `mapfile` and `declare` and added the ksh versions as aliases for them.  I don't know why)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `echo "$REAL_FILES"` you need to either concatenate the array into one string:

```
echo "${REAL_FILES[*]}"
```

Or you can do a per-element printout:

```
printf "%s\n" "${REAL_FILES[@]}"
```

Comment: Myabe I didn't explain well or perhaps I'm misinterpreting your answer, but my issue is not with the "echo," it is that when CHANGED_FILES contains two or more files, REAL_FILES never contains any values.